# How to compare two dates in sql with data type integer and char in db2?

Tags: types, db2

I am comparing two table HDSTD19 and HDSTD146

```
SELECT D146_PREF_DATE,D19_DIARY_DTE FROM 
HDSTD19,HDSTD146 WHERE D19_CONT_NO='M400252' D19_CONT_NO=D146_CONT_NO   
WITH UR;
```

Here I want to add a condition  where I can put D146_PREF_DATE=D19_DIARY_DTE
But D19_DIARY_date has datatype integer with format YYYYDDMM and D146_PREF_DATE has datatype char with format DD/MM/YYYY.

How can I add this, i am using DB2.

Thanks

Comment: I am writing my querries in java and trying to connect with backend using JDBC

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html) for this problem:

```
select *
from yourTable
where TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(D146_PREF_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  = TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(D19_DIARY_DTE, 'YYYYDDMM')
```